# Android APK Showing Blank Screen On Device

Tags: android, android-install-apk

I have an apk, I've been testing with friends for a while. Just recently, it stopped working and the app shows white screens on all activities. I have installed same app from Android Studio and via bluetooth to my phone and it works but not on my friends phones.

Is this a problem with the devices or Android Studio? Is this due to previous installations not being changed cos package name is same but the api end points and database have changed.

I have read here to change run configurations. Here's mine:
[image]

Comment: disable instant run from studio settings then try

Comment: It's disabled already

Comment: What's on logcat?

Comment: Are you sure that your min version is compatible with your friends one?

Comment: Yes, all devices are 16 and above and target sdk is 28

Comment: I cant see the logcat as my friend is a remote tester but there are no crashes